# Django : How to check a list of values is exists in a table or not in a single query in django?

Tags: python, sql, django, optimization, orm

user entered categoryIds = [1,2,3,............]

for catId in categoryIds:

```
if Category.objects.filter(id = catId).exist():
    --------------
    ----single opertions like adding value in to dict.-----
else:
    --------------
```

I need to avoid unnecassary iteration by checking it in a single query.
check the entered values is valid and then I can add to dict in a single step.

how can I do it with django ORM ?

eg :
Category.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2,3,4,5,6])
in case 5 is not a valid id present in Category, it shouldn't
enter in to next step.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) field lookup to filter from a list of values:

```
Category.objects.filter(id__in=categoryIds)
```

Then you can use `values_list` to retrieve the values from a given field in a queryset:

```
valid_categories = set(Category.objects.filter(id__in=categoryIds).values_list('id', flat=True))
```

Comment: appreciate your effort, but this is not what I want. Category.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2,3,4,5,6]),   in case 5 is not a valid id present in Category, it shouldn't enter in to next step.

Comment: Did you read the second part of my answer? It'll return all the valid categories through which you can then iterate.

Answer (score 0):

```
user_entered_category = [1,2,3,............]
```

assuming the above list contains ids(you can filter with other fields as well depending on your requirement.

```
to_be_created = []
existing_data = list(Model.objects.filter(id__in=user_entered_category).values_list("id",flat=True))

for data in existing_data:
    id data not in user_entered_category:
         to_be_created.append(
             ModelName(field_name=value_toset, and other fields.......)
)
```

then do bulk create:

```
Model.objects.bulk_create(to_be_created)
```